# not able to render element into screen by v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got data from a DB, stored it in an array, but could not render it with V-For, neither did I get any error or warning. I have following data on my db:

[image]

and here is my code:

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="item in userList" :key="item.uid">
      <p>{{item.fullName}}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { db } from "src/boot/firebase";
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      userList: []
    };
  },
  async created() {
    const q = query(
      collection(db, "userProfile"),
      where("verified", "==", true)
    );
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    let arr = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      let docData = doc.data();
      this.userList.unshift(docData);
    });
    console.log(this.userList)
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Btw, `created` is obsolete, options api and composition api can be used together but one is supposed to be replaced with another

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm facing the exact same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I think your problem is that you didn't make userList reactive ([Vue Docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#reactive-variables-with-ref)). Try this:

```
setup() {
  return {
    userList: ref([])
  };
},
```

and make sure you import ref:

```
import { ref } from 'vue';
```

When you use ref's you deal with the value they contain, rather than the ref directly, so anywhere you were using `this.userList`, you should now use `this.userList.value` (except in the template: templates know how to deal with refs).

Comment: Consider explaining how it's used because this will change the rest of the code. `this.userList.unshift` won't work.

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks for the suggestion - I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If You are using composition API put everything in setup function, there is no [created hook](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-lifecycle-hooks.html) here, so You can make function:

```
setup() {
  const userList = ref([]);
  const created = async () => {
    const q = query(
      collection(db, "userProfile"),
      where("verified", "==", true)
    );
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    let arr = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      let docData = doc.data();
      userList.value.unshift(docData);
    });
  };
  created();
  return {
    userList
  };
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue might be that templates need a single root node, and your `v-for` makes there be multiple roots in the template. Try wrapping it in a `<div>`.

Comment: I tried your suggested solution, nothing changed.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help. If I were debugging this, I'd try adding <div>{{userList}}</div> to the beginning of the template so I could see what userList looks like as a whole (is it undefined? empty list? does an error get thrown?), and then keep debugging from there. If it's still an empty list, what happens when you set it directly in created(), e.g. by `this.userList = [1,2,3]`. If this doesn't lead anywhere, see if changing the declaration of userList in setup() to set it to [1,2,3] changes anything. If this doesn't get you anywhere, feel free to make a jsfiddle and I'll take another look :)